# Voice identification for web apps

Tags: web-services, authentication, voice-recognition

What libraries / projects is to identify / authenticating to web apps using the voice?

Answer (score 1):

Since there are still no answers for this question and it's been two years, I feel like there should be at least *a* follow-up.

Authenticating to an app using your voice is a very complex and difficult subject. Each case would probably require severe customization and as of right now I believe there is no out-of-the-box working solution to do it. The subject of speech/speaker recognition is still an academic subject.

One might use [HTK](http://htk.eng.cam.ac.uk/) or [Sphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/) to build one's own authentication tool. It is entirely possible, though quite difficult and still prone to false positives and/or rejections.

As for authenticating in the web - it adds some technical difficulties which, however, can be overcome. You would have to somehow get a sample, either by using a java applet or flash (something that can acces the microphone anyway), then submit it for analysis (may happen in the same applet), then pass the results to your web application.

For anyone still thinking about the problem: I'd suggest building a [sphinx-4](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/sphinx4/) based Java applet for authentication. It is possible, though time-costly and requiring some advanced knowledge.